# Read nText using RecordSet

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows

I've a column with name `FIELD1` of datatype `ntext`.
How can I read an `nText` field using a `CRecordset` object?

```
CRecordset oRecSet(&oCDb);
drc = oRecSet.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, csSQLStr);
oRecSet.GetFieldValue(_T("FIELD1"), vrColValue);
```

Using default field value, I'm not getting the contents.

Comment: Why are you using `ntext`? It's been deprecated for **15** years. It's long past time you should have switched to an `nvarchar(MAX)`. `ntext` has significantly less functionality and is very likely to not exist in a (near) future version of SQL Server.

Comment: I know. I'm using an ancient database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a work around.
Since my data in nText fields were relatively small, I typecasted the nText field to nvarhcar(MAX) and used.